# Find who sends files over the internal network

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-transfer

In my office someone is having fun doing a stupid prank: he creates hundreds of  small text files and push them over the internal network on our desktops.  There is no firewall or other security mechanisms to stop you from doing it. Obviously each of my collegues negates and I'd like to find out who is the prankster :)

Is there any way to find out who sends a file over the network on your pc? I could not find a way to see who is the author of the file nor a way to be alerted when a network transfer is in act.

We all use Windows 10 Pro with admin rights. We are a very small team, that's why our network's security is not that high.

Comment: Right click one of the files -> Click "Properties" -> Click "Details" tab -> Look for "Owner" item where it should have who the owner is (hopefully it will be a user you can identify).

Comment: Unfortunately there is my name there, I've already checked

Comment: OK, yo may want to investigate turning on Windows Firewall logging. You can then match the file creation times with which computer is talking to your computer at the time the files are created. https://www.howtogeek.com/220204/how-to-track-firewall-activity-with-the-windows-firewall-log/

Comment: Additionally, you should be alerting your manager to this abuse of your network/computers.

Comment: Without knowing how the files are transferred (Windows File Sharing?), you cannot stop this. Where are the files on the affected PCs? Why is this folder accessible?

Answer (score 2):

Might be better suited to security.stackexchange.com, but...

The obvious first thing to check is the creator/owner of the file. Assuming you aren't doing anything crazy like actually sharing login credentials with each other, and instead have some Active Directory or similar system where each user has their own account, this can tell you who created the files. You can see this from the Properties dialog (Security tab, click Advanced and look for the Owner near the top of the window). Unfortunately, the owner of a file can be changed by any user with enough permissions, so your prankster could be covering his tracks / planting a false flag that way.

If the files are going to a specific directory (or single file path), you can turn on auditing for that directory / file and see when it gets written to, and by whom. Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Auditing, create a new rule for all users (or one for each suspect), and make sure that you are checking for create file/write and append/create dir operations. These operations will then appear in the security event log.

You can also check the logs for login / network events, but they might not get logged or might be lost in the noise.

If you catch the act in progress, use the `net session` command from an admin console (CMD or Powershell) to see who is currently using a network share on your computer, and what computer it is coming from.

Comment: Awesome! The auditing feature is exactly what I was looking for... let's wait for the mouse to fall in the trap :)

Answer (score 0):

To know what is going on your network without central control server you need to use sniffing tool like Wireshark

Read more here

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2018/05/25/network-tracing-packet-sniffing-built-in-to-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-server-2012-2/

Answer (score -1):

There is a very simple way of doing it.
If you have access to all the computers while everybody is away,
you may consult the network use on each computer by :

- Log into the computer
- Go into PC Settings -> Network & Internet
- Select "Data usage"
- You may now view the amount of data sent over the network in the last 30 days
  and the utilities used for that :

[image]